# Simple bound for number of labelled forests?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $F(n)$ be the number of labelled forests on $n$ vertices.  At the OEIS entry for this sequence https://oeis.org/A001858 , there is a claim that $F(n) \sim e^{1/2} n^{n-2}$.  I am interested in a much simpler result, which is that I would simply like to know that
for some constant $C$,
$$
F(n) \leq (Cn)^n.
$$
Is there an elementary combinatorial proof of this fact which does not use generating functions?  Perhaps for example there is an injective map taking forests to a function $f:[n]\to[10n]$.

I can for example get the bound
$$
F(n) \leq n^{2n}
$$
by arguing that a forest has at most $n$ edges, and there are fewer than $n^2$ edges to choose from.  This is a very inefficient way to count however since most graphs chosen this way form cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of forests is less than or equal to the number of rooted forests, where a rooted forest is a forest where one vertex in each component has been singled out as the root. The latter are exactly enumerated as
$$
\text{# labeled, rooted forests on $\{1,\dots,n\}$}=(n+1)^{n-1}
$$
This follows from Cayley's formula for the number of trees, since a labeled rooted forest on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is uniquely determined by choosing a labeled tree on $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, then deleting $0$ and all indcident edges, then declaring a vertex to be a root iff it was a neighbor of zero.

This bound suffices, since
$$
(n+1)^{n-1}=n^{n-1}\cdot (1+\tfrac1n)^{n-1}\le  n^{n-1}\cdot e
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for.